# How can I increase the performance in Edit Mode (ver 2.79/2.8beta) for my map project?

Tags: vertices

I am quite new to Blender and even newer at taking part in forums but there‘s always a first:

I am trying to create quite a detailed map for a videogame. It is supposed to become something like 1.700 km x 900 km big.

My problem: 
As I have subdivided my single mesh of a land mass into more vertices (aiming for faces equivalent of less or 1 squaremeter), I encountered the problem that having more than ~99k vertices makes my edit mode laggy and I would still have a long way to go to reach a level of detail that makes it not able to perform or even move around in the viewport without a tremendous amount of coffeebreaks.

My question: 
Is there a possibility to increase the performance of my edit mode? In older versions there was supposed to be a checkbox called „VBO“ in the system preferences, but I think I read it was removed for reasons I don‘t know.

Maybe my goal is a little too ambitioned, when I am using my ver
Macbook Pro 
2,6GHz intel core i7
16GB Ram
Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB 
On OSX El Capitan

If you have some advice for me, I would be glad!

Comment: How about splitting your map into separate pieces, which don't have that many polygons. Object mode and **sculpt** mode are also more performant in manipulating geometry.

Comment: you are using an integrated gpu, which do not adapt to such high performance requirements, on the other hand it seems inefficient and quite useless to make a mesh of such dimensions in one piece, I would think of generating the ground in a procedural way, in Logic bricks is possible to do something similar although

Comment: it requires a lot of work in the script, that is already a choice of what to take, or divide it into scenes and call each scene depending on how much progress you want to register and at what moment the next scene will appear, another is that maybe if I had 32GB of ram or more it could work without the dedicated gpu